# What is the purpose of Shathru samhara pooja?

Tags: temple, mantras, puja

Shathru Samhara pooja is believed to be done for destroying the enemies. This pooja is usually performed in temples.
 - What is the purpose of such pooja? 
 - Do this actually have any other meanings or is it supposed to destroy the enemies? 
 - Seems like there is a misconception about this pooja, can somebody elaborate the real purpose of this pooja?

Comment: If enemies are part of God, so is an tiger in the forest which would attack you. Would you invoke your flight or fight against the tiger or just stand still for it to eat you are you are only going to go inside God. From my knowledge of Advaita, the world is real until you realize the nirguna Brahman. Until that, the tiger is real, the enemy is real.

Comment: @Bharat: I have removed that sentence, since it will be broad to discuss in this question. Now the question is specific about the Shathru Samhara Pooja

Answer (score 3):

From [PriestServices](http://www.priestservices.com/our-services/shatru-samhara-homa):

> #### Significance:
>
> Lord Subramanya is the youngest son of Lord Shiva and goddess Parvathi. He is considered as god of love but at the same time a fierce to enemies. He never fails to instill fear in the heart of negative people and harmful entities.
>
> #### Lord Subramanya of Vedic times
>
> According to Rig Veda Lord Subramanya is considered as the overwhelming power. Moreover the sage Veda Vyas wrote Skanda Purana and Sangam Tamil Literature speaks of the Lord’s six abodes.
>
> #### Benefits of Shatrusamhara Homam:
>
> This Homa gives a person joy and authority. It protects and prevents one from evil eyes, curses of gods, planets and ancestors. It further enhances family relationship, removes dullness, fear, mental block, frees one from debts, helps to cure fatal diseases, bestows progeny; give good health and six Siddhis.
>
> Om Kartikeyaya Vidmahe
> Shakti Hastaya Dhimahi
> Tanna Skanda Prachodayat
>
> This Mantra is an armor which protects us from our enemies and gives courage to face them.
>
> #### Recommended to:
>
> - One who constantly face Enemies (military and police person)
> - One in Political Field
> - Business Competitors
> - Possessed with Black Magic, Eevil Eyes and Spirits
> - Ancestral Cruses
> - Suffering with Chronic Disease
> - And for protection from Negative Forces
>
> #### Legend
>
> Penance of Goddess Parvathi on Shiva got her married to Him. The purpose of marriage is to create lord Muruga and to kill the demon Surapadma. Lord Shiva took a form with six faces and from each third eye of the six faces, a fire spark came out. He asked the Gods of fire and wind to carry the sparks to River Ganges. Later Ganga took it to Sarvana pond. This six fire spark transformed into six beautiful babies who were nurtured by six Karthigai maids. Muruga has twelve hands but one face as Mother Parvathi merged the six faces into one. He is also known as Kumaran, Mayilvaganan, Kaangeyan, Velayuthan, Gugan etc.
>
> The demon Surapadma created terror to all gods. So, Lord Shiva decided to destroy him through Muruga. Muruga obtained 11 weapons and a Vel or spear from Shiva and Parvathi to vanquish the demon. He then fought for ten days, at Thiruchendur. Soorapadman took the form of a big mango tree which was split by the spear of Muruga and the two halves turned into a peacock (vehicle) and a cock (on flag) respectively.
>
> People also conduct 'Poorna Kriya' on the Amavasyas which is generally related with the birth of twins thus bringing contentment and peace in their life.

Answer (score 3):

The real essence of Shat Karmas is far forgotten in masses. Some, Bhanda tantrics for the only cause of monetary favours have resorted to Maran or Shatru Samhara Prayogas.

```
What is the purpose of such pooja?
```

In layman's term this is the ruital where end results are inflicting pain or death on the person. Or in milder way it makes them loose battles or destory everything they posses.

```
Seems like there is a misconception about this pooja, can somebody elaborate the real purpose of this pooja?
```

We remember the ancedote when Maharaj Dasharath fought Shani dev & Maharishi Pipalad discharged Dhumastra on Shani.
In both these cases, Shatru Samhara mantras were used by Dashrath & Pipalad on Shani. But, why?
Dasharatha used the mantra to defeat the Vakradrishti of Shani, because that caused droughts in his kingdom & his subjects suffered. Thus, for the welfare of masses he used the mantra. Pipalad used the mantra to teach Shani a lesson. For, at that time Shani became too proud of his Powers & was inflicting anyone with his Vakradrishti. Thus for the good of the universe he used the mantra.

But, this is far forgotten today. If someone pissed a person, they will resort to Shatru Samhara puja. This, is hysteric. For the real purpose is a far cry from this.

Moha Shastra, Shiva explains to Ravana,

> One must never resort to Maran, untill it is the life & death situation. If done in elseway, kills the sadhaka himself.

The real purpose was not to harm someone whom you deem as wrong. It was for Atma raksha when water went over the head.
Shiva, once again explains the use of this ritual,

> One should contemplate on all the injurious beings, cruel persons, those causing strife and pains, baselessly envicious, causing disturbances in worship, Evil spirits, secondary planets, goblins, ghosts, Yakshas, Rakshas, and all other harmful beings being falling in that fire and getting burnt up.

Thus, this was for the sadhakas who were been disturbed unnessscarily. Still, a true Sadhaka never uses Shatkarma.
Remember, how much Tara sadhaka Bamakhepa was ridiculed by other & even thrashed by Pandas of Tarapith? Did Bamadev do Maran?                         He was Tara siddh, if he had wanted everyone could have died a horrible death. But, he didn't, he just left everything at Maa.
Thus, when even Mahapurushas didn't resort to this malicious thing, you think our problems are bigger in this Mithya Jagad, a bubble of virtual experience?

```
Do this actually have any other meanings or is it supposed to destroy the enemies?
```

Indeed, in subtuler sense, Maran means to kill the malice in ourselves. To kill our own senses, so that we move faster on the path of liberation. Rather than killing someone, which will do nothing but add on to your karmas.

Firstly who are our real enemies?

Bhagwat geeta 3.41,

> Therefore, O best of the Bharatas, in the very beginning bring the senses under control and **slay this enemy called desire**, which is the embodiment of sin and destroys knowledge and realization.

3.43,

> Thus knowing the soul to be superior to the material intellect, O mighty armed Arjun, subdue the lower self (senses, mind, and intellect) by the higher self (strength of the soul), and **kill this formidable enemy called lust**.

For eg, various mantras appear, let us understand a few here.

While explaining outcomes of Marana shastra says,

> गतिस्तम्भो भवेदेवी चौरादीनाम् तथा खलु।
> The movements of Robbers with surely be stopped there, oh Devi!

> ....मृत्युरेव रिपोर्युवम्।
> The Ripu (enemy) will die.

Here robbers & enemies are not just the daicots in world. By robbers Shiva means the robbers of conciousness ie the **Shadripus**.

Vairagya Dindima,

> कामः क्रोधश्च लोभश्च देहे तिष्ठन्ति तस्कराः।
> ज्ञानरत्नापहाराय तस्मात् जाग्रत जाग्रत।।
> Desire, anger, greed, attachment, pride, jealousy these robbers are residing within your own body. They are not outside. To loot you of the Jnana-Ratna, to rob you of the precious gem of spiritual wisdom or atma-jnana, to loot you and deprive you of the precious gem of Self-awareness and make you forget your Self and weep and wail and be in ignorance. In order to deprive you of this jewel of atma-jnana, they are there. Therefore, oh man, oh Sadhak, beware, beware.”

Thus, in subtuler sense Marana kriya stop movements of those robbers & kills the enemies those called as Desire, Lust, Anger, etc. Therfore, opening the doors to liberation at more faster pace.

While describing the place to carry on Maran the shastra say,

> शुन्यागारे महारण्ये देवतायतनेsषी वा।
> In deserted place, dense forest, or in temple.

Here, Shunyagar doesnt mean desrted place, it means in a mind devoid of desires, dense forest means a mind which is quite as forest, temple means a mind fixed on ishta just as vigrahas are fixed in garbhagriha.
Thus signifying that one must beomce devoid of desires, have a tranquil mind, fix it on Isht devi & thus do Maran (kill) the internal enemies and the senses.

> ....निर्जने
> In a desolated place

Here, the desolated place means, the sadhaka must dettach in heart from everyone around him. He must dettach from Samsara & thus kill his own internal enemies.

> ... मारणन्तु शवोपरि।
> Do maran on the dead body.

Here, dead body is the sadhaka himself. When he goes in Samadhi, he looses the awareness of the external world & thus becomes just like a dead body.
Therefore, subtuly it hints here, to be meditated & win over internal enemies.

While mentioning thing to use,

> कपालं मारणं शुभम्।
> It is auspicious to use Skull in maran.

How can a skull be auspicious?
Thus, the answer is here. Skull is the mark of wisdom & knowledge. Shiva asks the sadhaka to use that wisdom & knowledge to do Maran (kill his own internal enemies).

Thus, it is evident that Maran & Shatra Mardana is meant for internal enemies. But, is used only under rare conditions for external affairs.

One such ancedote was in Kashi. When Islamic invaders were about to break into the city. The worried Pandits of Kashi went to Kalbhairava temple the guardian of Kashi to seek help. Thus, at night when all Pandits were sleeping. KalBhairava ordered them to evoke Ugra Ràm to protect Kashi. Early in the morning while discussing that they all had the common dream, thus, they considered it as true. And evoked Ugra Ràm with Paduka mantras & also discharged the Shatru Mardana Krama. To cut short, two soldiers were seen battling the islamic forces. And no one could understand where the invading army disappeared in the thin of air, even for they broke into Kashi.
Second anecdote - This Shastru Samhara Krama of Bhaglamukhi & Dhumavati was together used by Pitambara Peethadhishwara Maharaj against China army in the year 1962. And, as a result the war came to an end just within a month period that too with China backing off, and thus helping India gain an upper hand. It was after this, that Peetambara peeth became so famous.
Thus, such potent is the Shatru Samhara Krama. Unless foolish people use it to harm one another.

Thus, explicit warning appears in tantra for both the people who ask to do this to harm others for their trivial reasons & the Tantrics who do this for money.

> These self-seeking men, O Devi! would for the sake of wealth kill one another, and be full of sin by reason of their maliciousness and desire to thieve.

> In the doing of what is forbidden and in the omitting of what is enjoined men sin, and sins lead to pain, sorrow, and disease (14).

> O Kula-nayika! know that there are two kinds of sin – that which contributes merely to the injury of one’s own self, and that which causes injury to others.

> The Lord protects this universe. Whoever wish to destroy it will be themselves destroyed, and whosoever protect it them the Lord of the Universe Himself protects. Therefore should one act for the good of the world.

> Thou hast truly spoken, O Devi! of the ways of men, who, knowing what is for their welfare, yet, maddened by sinful desire for things which bring immediate enjoyment, and devoid of the sense of right and wrong, will desert the True Path.

**कालिकार्पणमस्तु ।**