# Are all poojas performed for god or can they be done for good/bad spirits also?

Tags: tradition, puja, evil

1. Are all the poojas done to god? Are there any poojas done seeking the help of evil spirits for any favour? I have heard of 'sathru samhara pooja.'
2. Is doing 'koodothram'(black magic) against hindu tradition?

Comment: Check Bhagavad Gita. Krishna has described different types of people, depending on their needs worship Gods, demons, ghosts etc.. but those who worship supreme Parabrahman alone attain Moksha.

Comment: Welcome to [Hinduism.se]. Please visit [ask] regarding help on asking questions. You have asked two different questions in a single post. Only one question per post please. Regarding Shatru samhara pooja, it is already asked [What is the purpose of Shathru samhara pooja?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2521/5212). If that answers your question, [edit] your question and focus on a single question.