# Mantra against Enemies?

Tags: mantras, stotra

Are there any Mantra, Stotra; requesting GOD to guard us against our enemies..
Protect us from internal enemies like [Shadripu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arishadvargas) and External enemies..

Comment: I have come across these two [Nirvana Shatakam](https://greenmesg.org/stotras/brahman/nirvana_shatakam.php) and Atharva Veda 8.4.22 which might help with internal enemies [Shadripu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arishadvargas) and Aditya Hridayam..

Comment: Im mostly looking for protection against internal enemies, enemies of mind..

Comment: [Shathru Samhara](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2521/what-is-the-purpose-of-shathru-samhara-pooja) , << is this a mantra, are there any mantra of Lord Subramanya for help against enemies..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can recite / read / listen Durga Kavach, This is a prayer to the Divine Mother for ultimate protection from all enemies, ghosts, complete body, fire, etc.

This is my personal favourite sung by Gundecha Brothers

**Video :**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rqgvyF9LBHk&list=RDMMrqgvyF9LBHk&start_radio=1

**Lyrics :** 
https://www.voidcan.org/durga-kavach/

You can also listen to the world famous **Hanuman Chalisa** or **Bajrang Baan** in that there are stanzas which provides protection. Bajrang Baan is very powerful in this there is a promise been given to **Hanumanji** of Lord Ram to serve the purpose.

From Bajrang Baan :

जय जय जय धुनि होत अकासा
सुमिरत होय दुसह दु:ख नाशा

चरन पकरी कर जोरि मनावौं
यहि अवसर अब केहि गोहरावहौं

उठ उठ चलु तोहि राम दुहाई
पाय परौं कर जोरि मनाई

ॐ चं चं चं चं चपल चलंता
ॐ हनु हनु हनु हन हनुु हनुमंता

Comment: Thanks :-).....

Comment: If the answer is satisfisable to you, please accept it.

Comment: Im just waiting for others answers :-)

Comment: ^^ above comment..