# Protection from Black Magic

Tags: mantras

Are there any *mantras* or *strotras* prescribed in *Tantric* and *Vedic* texts which protect a native **specifically** from black magic?

If so, what are they?

Comment: Mostly kavacha are used to prevent and protect, there are kavacha of many gods, as you like you can chant them daily. Shiva kavach, ramraksha etc etc. Going a little over it, there comes sadhana, more higher the indrajals. All way down nama japa is the best, and who can ignore the beautiful Gayatri mantra?

Comment: Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2552/647

Comment: Atharva Veda Samhitas. But the intonation must be done correctly by a brahmin well versed in the Atharva, or it can have the opposite effect.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Hmm, was waiting for this one. Could you specify them as an answer?

Comment: Go to any Gurudwara nearby and ask them to pray for you against any witchcraft or blackmagic. If possible ask the management for some seva. You will feel the difference. You can also visit a krishna temple where mangla-arti is offered and water offered to Bhagwan is sprinkled on the assembled devotees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are possibly many such Stotras and of course Mantras are there too.

For example, the [Sarva Roga Hara Maheswara Kavacham](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Sarva_Roga_Hara_Maheswara_Kavacham), dedicated to Lord Shiva, is one such Stotra/Kavacha.

Quoting few verses from the Phalasruthi below:

> 15.Iykahikam vaa dhyajhikam,
>  Vaa tritheeya chathurthakam,
>  Vatha pitha kaphod bhootham,
>  Sannipatho ugra thejasam.
>
> 16.Anyam dukha dhoora darsha karmajam cha **abhicharikam**, Dathustham kapha sammisram vishamam kama sambhavam.
>
> Reading this daily or once in two days, Or once in three days or once
> in four days., Would remove diseases caused by rheumatism, bile and
> phlegm , And those by evil spirits and the very severe collection of
> them .
>
> Other sorrows caused by actions from far off or **black magic**, Or
> problems caused metal and phlegm and problems caused by passion,
>
> 17.Bhoothabhishanga samsargam Bhootha cheshtadhi samsthitham,
>  Shivagnam Ghora manthrena Poorva vrutham swayam smara.
>
> In case of the visits of ghosts or when troubles are caused by ghosts,
> Remember this powerful chant told before as per the orders of Lord
> Shiva.
>
> 18.Thyaja deham manushyasya dheepam gacha Maha jwara,
>  Krutham thu kavacham divyam sarva vyadhi bhayrdhanam.
>
> When man’s soul goes away from the body due to great fever The above
> divine armour would completely remove the fear of disease.

And, I believe there are many other Stotras having the same benefit. However, if the black magic done is too powerful then dedicated Pujas have to be performed by learned Pundits as a remedial measure. I doubt whether reading Stotras by oneself work (as completely effective remedies) in those cases or not.